# how to tackle .. Credentials flag is 'true' CORS errors

Tags: angularjs, express

I am running an ionic app on http://localhost:8100 which connects to my express backend that is running on http://localhost:3000.

As usual I am facing CORS issue. disabling websecurity in chrome did not help.

The error that chrome reports is :

```
(index):1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook. 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check:
Credentials flag is 'true', 
but the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header is ''. 
It must be 'true' to allow credentials. 
Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.


Remote Address:[::1]:3000
Request URL:http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 OK

Response Headers
view source
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:accept, content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:8100
Access-Control-Max-Age:31536000
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:2
Content-Type:text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date:Wed, 04 Nov 2015 02:25:07 GMT
ETag:W/"2-d736d92d"
X-Powered-By:Express


Request Headers
view source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Connection:keep-alive
DNT:1
Host:localhost:3000
Origin:http://localhost:8100
Referer:http://localhost:8100/
```

First question is: 
I do not see any Access-Controll-Allow-Credentials Flag in the request headers, then why is chrome complaining

Second questions:
I have tried using CORS express module but that did not help. How do I overcome this issue ?

Comment: Were you able to find the answer by yourself? If so, please write the answer, so other people like me can benefit from it X)

Comment: @RicardoPanaggio .. answer posted

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by including the following piece of middleware in my nodejs server

```
var app = express();
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

app.use(accessControl);
```

where the function accessControl looks like below:

```
function(req, res, next) {

  var oneof = false;

  if (req.headers.origin) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
    oneof = true;
  }
  if (req.headers['access-control-request-method']) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', req.headers['access-control-request-method']);
    oneof = true;
  }
  if (req.headers['access-control-request-headers']) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', req.headers['access-control-request-headers']);
    oneof = true;
  }
  if (oneof) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Max-Age', 60 * 60 * 24 * 365);
  }

  if (req.originalUrl === '/auth/signup') {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  }

  if (req.originalUrl === '/auth/login') {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  }

  // intercept OPTIONS method
  if (oneof && req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    res.sendStatus(200);
  }

  else {
    next();
  }
};
```

This is not an elegant solution but it did the trick for me (atleast until I figure out something better)